# how to simulate a click event in javascript

Tags: javascript

i open a website ,after choosing an item ,a popup appear with "OK" button to confirm .
i use this `var btn = document.getElementById('btnAddedSuccess');
btn.onclick();` to execute the "OK click event " ,but it didnt do the job

Can you help me the code to press the OK button .

The html tag information of the button is :`<a id="btnAddedSuccess" class="ui-button" href="javascript:;">OK</a>`

Thanks much !

Comment: this is its information :<a id="btnAddedSuccess" class="ui-button" href="javascript:;">OK</a>

Comment: You can use ` for adding code (see edits)... or use the "Code Sample" button `{}` in the editor. Also, what is the question? It's not clear what you want to do or what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks mike ,like i said ,i want to create a javacript which can click on an OK Button on a POP UP

Comment: This code of Sergio Aristizábal : `var btn = document.getElementById('btnAddedSuccess');
btn.onclick();`  .It seems right ,but i did not work

Comment: Are you looking for [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/R557n/1/

Comment: im looking for code could execute "click event"

Comment: ... yeah. That is what is shown in my fiddle. Both confirm and a `div` that executes `click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate a click event, you can use the `onclick` event:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btnAddedSuccess');
btn.onclick();
```

Comment: it couldnt do it , "btn is null" ,the button OK is on a pop up ,fist i click on an item ,after that a pop up appear with OK Button .and i want to click on this OK button .

Comment: So you will need to call this code after the pop up appear. Probably you should post that code too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a id="btnAddedSuccess" class="ui-button ui-button-primary ui-button-medium" href="javascript:;" onclick='fun()'>OK</a> 

<script>
function fun(){
    alert("OK");
}
</script>
```

You can use **onclick** event to call a javascript function '**fun()**'. and perform your needed operation in that function.

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89Pq6/)

Comment: do you want to fire the click event after running the code?

Comment: it seems  you misunderstand what i mean ?

Comment: yes I still don't understand what output you actually need

Comment: hi Myth ,look that the solution of Sergio Aristizábal ,i use chrome web to surf internet ,and when i join a web ,i click on an item ,it appear a windows which contain "OK button",you can click on OK button ,but i want to use console of chrome by press F12 key ,- >console ,and paste javascipt code ,and after paste and press enter ,the OK BUTTON pressed .Understand me ???

Comment: Do you want to focus on the button so that when you press enter it will execute click event?

Comment: No ,i want : after execute the code ,the "OK BUTTON" will be press !

Comment: after execute the code , it will execute click event . Sorry for my poor english !